# Group rows in google sheets and create google slides via appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this Google sheet table. I want to send this data to Google slides

[image: Google Sheet Data]

I would like to group rows in one slide. For instance, A to C can be grouped in one slide and D to F can be grouped in another slide. Or maybe group D and F together in one slide and A to C in individual slides. So I want a code that accounts for these conditions.

Currently, I have the below script mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77514133/retrieve-values-from-google-sheet-to-google-slides-are-not-populating-results/77514255#77514255). This script creates slides for each row and works perfectly fine.

```
function newPresentation() {
  let templateId = "XXX";
  let presentationTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId);
  let copy = presentationTemplate.makeCopy().getId();
  let deck = SlidesApp.openById(copy);
  let slides = deck.getSlides();
  let dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange();


  
  const ar = ["{{item}}", "{{results}}"]; // Sample object for replacing the placeholders.
  const [, ...sheetContents] = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
  slides.forEach((slide, i) => ar.forEach((f, j) => slide.replaceAllText(f, sheetContents[i][j])));
}
```

**Here is the final result sample that I want** - https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1jKXnvhINF2Qz1CYn9BpzHW0Xuj_cZ_Q1IULZpe8Sjp4/edit?usp=sharing

**Here is the Master Template** - https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1NM1gUIkiOk7bRA2VhDScoa-8ph-6ike6Fuyrv4ngcuw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems that your provided Google Slide is your expected result. Also, can you provide your template Google Slide?

Comment: Here is the template: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1NM1gUIkiOk7bRA2VhDScoa-8ph-6ike6Fuyrv4ngcuw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have modified the slides with some correction

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided template Slide, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your provided template Google Slide, it seems that pages 2 and 3 have the placeholders. But, in that case, only one kind of placeholder is used. It's `{{item}} - {{results}}`. And, `{{item}} - {{results}}` is used 3 times on every page. In this case, I would like to propose the modification of your placeholder of `{{item}} - {{results}}` for being a simple script. It's as follows.

- Page 2

  - Please modify 3 placeholders of `{{item}} - {{results}}` as follows.
  - `{{item1}} - {{results1}}`, `{{item2}} - {{results2}}` and `{{item3}} - {{results3}}`.
- Page 3

  - Please modify 3 placeholders of `{{item}} - {{results}}` as follows.
  - `{{item1}} - {{results1}}`, `{{item2}} - {{results2}}` and `{{item3}} - {{results3}}`.

In this answer, I would like to propose a modified script using these modified placeholders. So, before you test my script, please do the above modification of your placeholder.

By the way, when I saw your expected result, it seems that the result of the 3rd page is `D - This is item A`, `E - This is item B`, and `F - This is item F`. From your showing Spreadsheet, I guessed that those might be `D - This is item D`, `E - This is item E`, and `F - This is item F`. Please be careful about this.

The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script.

```js
function newPresentation() {
  let templateId = "XXX";
  let presentationTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId);
  let copy = presentationTemplate.makeCopy().getId();
  let deck = SlidesApp.openById(copy);
  let slides = deck.getSlides();
  let dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange();

  // I modified the below script.
  const ar = ["{{item#}}", "{{results#}}"];
  const [, ...sheetContents] = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
  const values = [...Array(Math.ceil(sheetContents.length / 3))].map((_) => sheetContents.splice(0, 3)); // ref: https://github.com/tanaikech/UtlApp#splitarray
  slides.shift();
  slides.forEach((slide, i) =>
    values[i].forEach((g, k) =>
      ar.forEach((f, j) => slide.replaceAllText(f.replace(/#/, k + 1), g[j]))
    )
  );
}
```

- When this script is run to the modified template Google Slide,

  - On page 2, `{{item1}} - {{results1}}`, `{{item2}} - {{results2}}` are replaced with `A - This is item A.`, `B - This is item B.` and `C - This is item C.`
  - On page 3, `{{item1}} - {{results1}}`, `{{item2}} - {{results2}}` are replaced with `D - This is item D.`, `E - This is item E.` and `F - This is item F.`

Comment: Thanks for this. It works perfectly fine. Can you explain this part ```...Array(Math.ceil(array.length / size))].map((_) =>
    array.splice(0, size)```

Comment: @Arif Ahmed Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `[...Array(Math.ceil(sheetContents.length / 3))].map((_) => sheetContents.splice(0, 3));`, the array of `sheetContents` is split every 3 rows. Because in your situation, 3 rows are used on a page. So, I split the rows of the Spreadsheet every 3 rows. The details of this can be also seen at [my repository](https://github.com/tanaikech/UtlApp#splitarray).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I went over your utility tool box. It's quite helpful. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Arif Ahmed Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: The above solution works well, how can we group in uneven chunks? The above solution works for size 3. How can we group in uneven chunks  2,3,2,3,4,2,2,1,9 ?

Comment: @Arif Ahmed About your new question, I would like to support you. But that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Yes sure. I will post a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77665251/group-rows-in-uneven-sizes-in-google-sheets-and-create-google-slides-via-appscri