# Group rows in uneven sizes in google sheets and create google slides via appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this Google sheet table and I want to group them into uneven sizes such `2,3,2,3,4,2,2,1,9` and then create Google slides. Below is just an example of the rows.

[image: Group Uneven Sizes]

I have this code that groups rows into 3.

```
function newPresentation() {
  let templateId = "XXX";
  let presentationTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId);
  let copy = presentationTemplate.makeCopy().getId();
  let deck = SlidesApp.openById(copy);
  let slides = deck.getSlides();
  let dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange();

  // I modified the below script.
  const ar = ["{{audit#}}", "{{results#}}"];
  const [, ...sheetContents] = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
  const values = [...Array(Math.ceil(sheetContents.length / 3))].map((_) => sheetContents.splice(0, 3)); // ref: https://github.com/tanaikech/UtlApp#splitarray
  slides.shift();
  slides.forEach((slide, i) =>
    values[i].forEach((g, k) =>
      ar.forEach((f, j) => slide.replaceAllText(f.replace(/#/, k + 1), g[j]))
    )
  );
}
```

The above code is working fine, however, I need to group uneven rows. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const values = [...Array(Math.ceil(sheetContents.length / 3))].map((_) => sheetContents.splice(0, 3)); // ref: https://github.com/tanaikech/UtlApp#splitarray
```

#### To:

```
const values = [2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 9].map(e => sheetContents.splice(0, e));
```

#### Note:

- In the case of the chunk sizes of `2,3,2,3,4,2,2,1,9`, the rows are required to be the 1st to 29th rows. But, in your showing image, only the 21 rows exist. In that case, I guessed that `2,3,2,3,4,2,2,1,9` might be required to be `2,3,2,3,4,2,2,1,2`. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Thank You, Tanaike. This works well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Arif Ahmed Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to consider creating your groups:

The data is just data that I generate with code for working on SO examples.

Sheet0:

[image]

You can use a validation list to select which groups you wish each row to be in and then run the below code:

gs:

```
function myfunk101() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  osh.clearContents();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();//without this the sheets update does not like to work.  Do not know why.
  const [hs, ...vs] = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss.getId(), `${sh.getName()}!${"A1:D"}`).values;
  let os = vs.reduce((a, r, i) => {
    let p = r[3];
    if (!a.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      a[p] = [r];
      a.pA = [...a.pA, p];
    } else {
      a[p] = [...a[p], r];
    }
    return a;
  }, { pA: [], output:function(){return this.pA.sort((x,y) => x - y).map(p => this[p].map(r => r) )} }).output();
  os.unshift([hs]);
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(os).replace(/]],/g, ']],\n').replace(/],/g, '],\n'));
  os.forEach(e => {
    let lr = osh.getLastRow();
    let a1 = !lr ? osh.getRange(1, 1).getA1Notation() : osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1).getA1Notation();
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: e }, ss.getId(), `${osh.getName()}!${a1}`, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" })
  });
}
```

And the is the output in Sheet1:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | Group |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 | 1 |
| 3 | A10 | B10 | C10 | 1 |
| 4 | A18 | B18 | C18 | 1 |
| 5 | A19 | B19 | C19 | 1 |
| 6 | A20 | B20 | C20 | 1 |
| 7 | A21 | B21 | C21 | 1 |
| 8 | A22 | B22 | C22 | 1 |
| 9 | A23 | B23 | C23 | 1 |
| 10 | A24 | B24 | C24 | 1 |
| 11 | A25 | B25 | C25 | 1 |
| 12 | A26 | B26 | C26 | 1 |
| 13 | A3 | B3 | C3 | 2 |
| 14 | A11 | B11 | C11 | 2 |
| 15 | A4 | B4 | C4 | 3 |
| 16 | A12 | B12 | C12 | 3 |
| 17 | A5 | B5 | C5 | 4 |
| 18 | A13 | B13 | C13 | 4 |
| 19 | A6 | B6 | C6 | 5 |
| 20 | A14 | B14 | C14 | 5 |
| 21 | A7 | B7 | C7 | 6 |
| 22 | A15 | B15 | C15 | 6 |
| 23 | A8 | B8 | C8 | 7 |
| 24 | A16 | B16 | C16 | 7 |
| 25 | A9 | B9 | C9 | 8 |
| 26 | A17 | B17 | C17 | 8 |

- [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [How to make a data table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/206484)
- [Using Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values)